# How to unit test with ILogger in ASP.NET Core, check args

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ilogger

I have a method:

```
public class MyLogger
{
    void DoLog(int objectId)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(
            new EventId(123),
            "Logging stuff",
            new MyMetric
            {
                ObjectId = objectId            
            });
    }
}
```

This test works:

```
public class MyLoggerTest
{
    [Fact]
    void ShouldLog()
    {
        var loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<MyLogger>>();
        var metricsLogger = new MyLogger(loggerMock.Object);
        metricsLogger.DoLog(234));

        loggerMock.Verify(
            x => x.Log(
                LogLevel.Information,
                It.Is<EventId>(e => e.Id == 123),
                It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((object v, Type _) => v.ToString().Contains("Logging stuff")),
                It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                It.Is<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>((v, t) => true)),
            Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Now how to check that objectId (234) is logged?

Comment: Your test confirms that the logger was called with event ID 123, what more do you need to test?

Comment: I've had trouble mocking ILogger before too, because it's funneled through extension methods and a ton of overloads that makes it hard to figure out what implementation is actually used and what types are going into it

Comment: @Jonesopolis ILogger only has a single method that makes a log, and OP is mocking it here

Comment: @davidG I simplified code for clarity, there are more params; imagine I have
`DoLog(int objectId, bool flag)` (objectid and flag being passed further to MyMetric)
`LogGood(id) => DoLog(id, true)`
`LogBad(id) => DoLog(id, false)`
and I want to test that LogGood calls LogInformation with `false` in MyMetric